# Activity Stopped when add the Load More button in Android

Tags: android

I am adding Load More button to the result to a page in Android. Activity is stopped when add the Load more button to the footer. I am using a custom adpater to display the results. Below is the code.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // LoadMore button
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

            // Adding Load More button to listview at bottom
            lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Starting a new async task
                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
            }
        });
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String cid = intent.getStringExtra("an1");
        //Log.v("blah", cid);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        // increment current page
        current_page += 1;
        // Next page request
        String url_all_products = "http://exa.com/get_product.php?page=" + current_page;


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", cid));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String img_url = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
                    String Platform = c.getString(TAG_PLATFORM);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_IMG, img_url);
                    map.put(TAG_PLATFORM, Platform);



                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {



                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NoProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                     ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);    
                    CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this, productsList);        
                     list1.setAdapter(cus);                 

                            }
                });

            }

        }
```

Logcat:

```
01-26 05:18:13.940: E/Trace(1094): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-26 05:18:18.330: D/libEGL(1094): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-26 05:18:18.433: D/(1094): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1825c8, tid 1094
01-26 05:18:18.462: D/libEGL(1094): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-26 05:18:18.479: D/libEGL(1094): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-26 05:18:18.800: W/EGL_emulation(1094): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-26 05:18:18.890: D/OpenGLRenderer(1094): Enabling debug mode 0
01-26 05:18:28.189: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 6% free 2718K/2884K, paused 349ms, total 404ms
01-26 05:18:28.209: I/dalvikvm-heap(1094): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.842MB for 1127536-byte allocation
01-26 05:18:28.629: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3816K/3988K, paused 413ms, total 413ms
01-26 05:18:29.219: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3817K/3988K, paused 43ms+175ms, total 577ms
01-26 05:18:30.590: W/EGL_emulation(1094): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-26 05:18:31.389: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:33.540: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_CONCURRENT freed 57K, 4% free 4189K/4364K, paused 16ms+47ms, total 206ms
01-26 05:18:36.230: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:37.920: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:39.730: D/dalvikvm(1094): GC_CONCURRENT freed 57K, 4% free 4610K/4784K, paused 7ms+8ms, total 222ms
01-26 05:18:40.010: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:40.430: W/EGL_emulation(1094): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-26 05:18:41.480: W/EGL_emulation(1094): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-26 05:18:41.530: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:43.900: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:46.269: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:47.509: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:18:55.699: E/JSON Parser(1094): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
01-26 05:18:56.150: W/dalvikvm(1094): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:234)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-26 05:18:57.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     ... 4 more
01-26 05:18:59.460: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:19:01.160: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:19:01.480: W/EGL_emulation(1094): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-26 05:19:02.340: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094): Activity com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40ef3bc0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-960,192} that was originally added here
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40ef3bc0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-960,192} that was originally added here
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:205)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:94)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-26 05:19:05.460: E/WindowManager(1094):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 05:19:05.480: I/Choreographer(1094): Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-26 05:19:06.890: I/Process(1094): Sending signal. PID: 1094 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for any help!.

Comment: Btw.: onPostExecute will already be executed on UI-Thread. There is no need to call runOnUI.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because you have a NullPointerException. See your logcat: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.esoftall.esoft.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:234)`.

The NullPointerException is causing premature termination of your application since the exception has not been caught. By investigating your doInBackground method, probably at the indicated line 234 of AllProductsActivity class, you might be able to establish why your application is failing. Otherwise without that said class, we may not be able to assist you more that this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @patwanjau. I updated the code with doInBackground. Please check it if you find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all!. it is working when i pass parameters using params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", Integer.toString(current_page))); instead of from url